# JPA2 persistence for a @ManyToMany Map containing a Set

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I need to persist a member with the type `Map<Item, Set<Item>>`, using JPA2 annotations.
The relation is many to many and Item objects are entities.

Should I create a separate intermediary Entity holding `Set<Item>` or is a direct mapping possible?

Please advise if some context is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I create a separate intermediary Entity holding `Set<Item>` or is a direct mapping possible?

JPA doesn't support nested collection relationships (`List` of `List`s, `Map` of `Set`s, etc). Here is the relevant section of the specification about `Map`:

> #### 2.7 Map Collections
>
> Collections of elements and entity
>   relationships can be represented as
>   java.util.Map collections.
>
> The map key and the map value independently can each be **a basic
>   type, an embeddable class, or an
>   entity.**
>
> ...

So yes, use an entity holding the `Set<Item>` and then map your relation as `Map<Item, MyHolder>`.

#### References

- JPA 2.0 specification

  - Section 2.7 "Map Collections"
- JPA Wiki Book

  - [Nested Collections, Maps and Matrices](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices)

Comment: Thanks a lot Pascal. Not exactly what I was hoping for, but at least I know I only have one possible solution here.